# update prepared statement to update user input information in java

Tags: java, jdbc

The error i receive is : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

String sourceURL = "jdbc:odbc:studentdb";
            String driverName = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";

```
        String BName = txtDate.getText();
        String AName = txtadd.getText();
        String CName = txtCon.getText();
        String Search = txtSeaNam.getText();
       try{ 
      Class.forName(driverName);
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(sourceURL,"","");

      Statement ins = conn.createStatement();
      String Insert = "UPDATE student SET Address = '%"+AName+"%', ContactDetails = '%"+CName+"%', DateOfBirth = '%"+BName+"%'"
              + " WHERE Name = '%"+Search+"%' and ContactDetails = '%"+Search+"%' and DateOfBirth = '%"+Search+"%'";
      PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(Insert);


      st.setString(1, BName);
      st.setString(2, AName);
      st.setString(3,CName);
      st.executeUpdate();

  }catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e){
      System.out.println(e.toString());
  }
```

Please help with error. thanks

Comment: also: do yourself a favour and look into naming conventions

Comment: That query is not going to work...